# На чем зарабатывают разработчики расширений?

Tags: chrome-extension

Есть масса полезных расширений, например grammarly, для проверки орфографии. Эта масса полезных расширений бесплатная, но в то же время кем то поддерживается и даже обновляется. Логичный вопрос, чем покрываются расходы, если расширения бесплатные?

Comment: Вас удивляет, что существуют люди, которые в принципе что-то делают для других (например, пишут код) бесплатно?

Comment: Вы можете начать работать бесплатно, если считаете иначе)

Comment: Работа это то, за что платят деньги. А кроме нее у людей бывают развлечения (это приносит удовольствие, прекрасно, когда работа вместе с деньгами приносит и удовольствие -)). Они у разных людей разные. Для некоторых написание софта -- это развлечение